# $scope.modalInstance.close(); what are the parametres i can pass?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

what are the parameters i can pass? and how the parameters  will affect  the

behaviour of the model.

```
  $scope.modalInstance.close();
```

Comment: "close(result) (Type: function) - Can be used to close a modal, passing a result." - [modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) .. For instance, your `$scope.editable` object